# React Apollo form

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I have a problem with my code here

```
function NewUser() {
  let input;
  const [newuser, { data }] = useMutation(NEW_USER);

  return (
    <div>
      <form
        onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          newuser({ variables: { username: input.value, email: input.value, password: input.value } });
          input.value = "";
        }}
      >
        <input
          className="mb2"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Nom"
          ref={node => {
            input = node;
          }}
        />
        <input
          className="mb2"
          type="email"
          placeholder="Mail"
          ref={node => {
            input = node;
          }}
        />
        <input
          className="mb2"
          type="password"
          placeholder="Mot de passe"
          ref={node => {
            input = node;
          }}
        />
        <button type="submit">S'inscrire</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

when I enter an email, it does not fit all of what I get. 
I have the impression that as soon as I put a point he stops reading my entry.
If you have an idea ?

```
variables: {username: "serveur", email: "serveur", password: "serveur"}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I enter my data, I had this [response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcEsI.jpg)